# Generate Cartesian product of List in Java

Tags: java, combinatorics

My code, which generates Cartesian product of all lists given as arguments:

```
public static <T> List<List<T>> cartesianProduct(List<T>... lists) {

    List<List<T>> product = new ArrayList<List<T>>();

    for (List<T> list : lists) {

        List<List<T>> newProduct = new ArrayList<List<T>>();

        for (T listElement : list) {

            if (product.isEmpty()) {

                List<T> newProductList = new ArrayList<T>();
                newProductList.add(listElement);
                newProduct.add(newProductList);
            } else {

                for (List<T> productList : product) {

                    List<T> newProductList = new ArrayList<T>(productList);
                    newProductList.add(listElement);
                    newProduct.add(newProductList);
                }
            }
        }

        product = newProduct;
    }

    return product;
}
```

Can this code be simplified?

Answer (score 5):

- You should read about the diamond operator.  You don't need to write the types on the right hand side in some circumstances.
- I avoid varargs because they confuse the type system.  My guess is that you are not using an IDE because mine (Netbeans) flags both the diamond operators and the varargs.
- You can indeed shorten your code because you don't really need to do a conditional check on the empty list if you start with the right conditions:

  ```
  public static <T> List<List<T>> computeCombinations2(List<List<T>> lists) {
      List<List<T>> combinations = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList());
      for (List<T> list : lists) {
          List<List<T>> extraColumnCombinations = new ArrayList<>();
          for (List<T> combination : combinations) {
              for (T element : list) {
                  List<T> newCombination = new ArrayList<>(combination);
                  newCombination.add(element);
                  extraColumnCombinations.add(newCombination);
              }
          }
          combinations = extraColumnCombinations;
      }
      return combinations;
  }
  ```

  Note that the scanning order changed: the first element stays fixed until all other combinations of the other elements are exhausted.  I prefer that order actually.
- It think it would be cleaner to split this in two methods.  There is a sub-task of adding one list of elements to an existing set of combinations and the main task which must call the sub-task on all lists:

  ```
  public static <T> List<List<T>> computeCombinations3(List<List<T>> lists) {
      List<List<T>> currentCombinations = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList());
      for (List<T> list : lists) {
          currentCombinations = appendElements(currentCombinations, list);
      }
      return currentCombinations;
  }
  ```

  and the sub-task (using Java 8):

  ```
  public static <T> List<List<T>> appendElements(List<List<T>> combinations, List<T> extraElements) {
      return combinations.stream().flatMap(oldCombination
              -> extraElements.stream().map(extra -> {
                  List<T> combinationWithExtra = new ArrayList<>(oldCombination);
                  combinationWithExtra.add(extra);
                  return combinationWithExtra;
              }))
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
  ```

  Actually, for this method, Java 8 does not make it shorter and makes it less readable than the old style.  I am leaving it nonetheless so you (and others) can get more familiar with Java 8.
- Minor point: I think you use too many blank lines in your code.

Comment: See this [gist](https://gist.github.com/max333/3cfafa146aeee29bee2a) for the code with a running example.